# Apache using different PHP version than the CLI

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4, homebrew

Firstly, please forgive me if this is in the wrong section (and could you tell where this should be?)

- I am starting to use Laravel, and it requires PHP with Mcrypt.
- So I followed the tutorial for Homebrew and have got PHP5.4 set up with Mcrypt
- Typing `which php` and `php -v` at the terminal all confirm that this PHP 5.4.24 is loaded and are ready to go.

However, the output of `phpinfo()` in the localhost directory (via Apache) shows I am using PHP 5.4.17 with no Mcrypt.

**OK, so I know I should have set up the httpd.conf with:**
 `LoadModule php5_module    /usr/local/opt/php54/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`

And when I do that, I get the right PHP version in Apache, but PHP seems to fail in subdirectories.

I have a file `index.php` at `localhost/test` containing `<? echo phpinfo();?>`, and...

...it works when the line in httpd.conf says this: `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`...

...but does **not** work when I change to homebrew's suggestion.

Any ideas?

### TL;DR...

When I set up `httpd.conf` to work with php54 (installed via Homebrew), then PHP is executed in the home directory of localhost, but not in the subdirectories.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. You have a working PHP set-up. You need an extension that's not available. So you decide that PHP is simply not working. Extensions can be enabled and disabled. In Unix it's often a matter of installing the appropriate package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I tried really hard to avoid the words 'php not working' as I know that's unhelpful. I hoped my summary (at the end) described the problem better. I really didn't say that I thought PHP was 'not working', just that it wasn't being executed.

Anyway, for anyone else who has this issue, I resolved it - see my own answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Oh. You. Idiot.

[This post](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,75272,75328) proves that I am, without a doubt, the biggest fool that walked the earth.

Clearly, short tags are turned off in the newer version of PHP but not in the older one.

So everything *was* working fine - if only I had used `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` then I could have saved about 8 hours of tears.

Comment: That's the problem with "does not work" descriptions. If you had mentioned you were getting a blank page we would have suggested to see the page source, inspect the status code and read apache logs ;-)

Comment: (Its usually the simplest thing that you forget to check)